# PC screen goes blank when attempting to enter UEFI/BIOS

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi

I am following the steps below to get into BIOS, but when I click restart at the end, my pc restarts, but never enters BIOS. It shows the pc make (Asus) and then goes to a blank screen.

I try hitting f2 or delete in this blank screen after a while, bit this resolves nothing.

Is there something else I should be doing or something I should do once the screen is blank?

Navigate to settings. ...

Select Update & security.

Select Recovery from the left menu.

Click Restart Now under Advanced startup. ...

Click Troubleshoot.

Click Advanced options.

Select UEFI Firmware Settings.

Click Restart.

Comment: What model number is your PC?

Comment: @misha256 DT ASUS M32AD-US032S RT

Comment: OK it seems that the BIOS screen is not being shown on the video output you're using.  At the back of your PC you'll see three video ports, DVI, HDMI, and VGA.  I've seen many cases where HDMI port does not show the BIOS screen.  If you can, try using the DVI or VGA port (if you have the cables and your monitor/tv supports them).  A pain I know!

Comment: @misha256 I am currently using a VGA port. Any other ideas or should I try a dvi as well?

Comment: Definitely try DVI.  It *should* work.

Comment: @misha256 No luck with the DVI cable. It still only shows the black screen. Any other ideas?